Is "shout to someone for help" correct?

"Juliano was always joking with me, saying, 'Nabil, one day I'll be shot in the head in the street and I'll shout to you for help,' " said Nabil al-Raee, 32, the director of the theater's acting school. From The New York Times

I've never seen the structure "shout to someone for help". "Shout for help" or "Shout for someone to help" seems far more common. Also, I've tried to find some other sentences in some corpora but got no results. So I wonder if the usage of "shout to someone for help" is acceptable? If so, could you give some more sentences from reliable sources?

It's fine.  They shouted to us for help. [from the sinking boat]. shouted to someone is very common. So is: for help. Try googling this: He shouted to me for help. Lots of hits.

Often, a "shout for help" is just a shout out to anyone for help - anyone that might hear.
Adding "to you" just makes the shout more specific - in the direction of a particular person. There's nothing unusual about it.

Though I couldn't find an exact match for shout to someone for help, a similar phrase shout to him for help is valid; we can replace him with someone and use it in a similar manner.
